# '<GoogleUtilities/GULLoggerLevel.h>' file not found when using Firebase AND MLKit/translate

Tags: xcode, firebase, swiftui, google-mlkit

I've created a new swiftui project in Xcode 14.1 on a MacBook Air M1

It will build and run if I add these pods

pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
pod 'GoogleMLKit/Translate', '3.2.0'

**OR**

pod 'FirebaseStorage'
pod 'GoogleMLKit/Translate', '3.2.0'

**OR**

pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
pod 'FirebaseStorage'

But if I try to add all three pods together (

'FirebaseStorage'
'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
'GoogleMLKit/Translate', '3.2.0'

) the project will not build and the Xcode error is:

~/Pods/GoogleUtilitiesComponents/GoogleUtilitiesComponents/Sources/GULCCComponentContainer.m:22:9 'GoogleUtilities/GULLogger.h' file not found

There are also these warnings in the terminal after `pod install` but only when installing the three problematic pods together.

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.24)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (3.4.2)
Installing FirebaseCore (10.1.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreExtension (10.1.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreInternal (10.1.0)
Installing FirebaseFirestore (10.1.0)
Installing FirebaseFirestoreSwift (10.1.0)
Installing FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.9)
Installing FirebaseSharedSwift (10.1.0)
Installing FirebaseStorage (1.0.4)
Installing GTMSessionFetcher (1.7.2)
Installing GoogleDataTransport (9.2.0)
Installing GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.2.2)
Installing GoogleMLKit (3.2.0)
Installing GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.2)
Installing GoogleToolboxForMac (2.3.2)
Installing GoogleUtilities (1.3.2)
Installing GoogleUtilities (7.10.0)
Installing GoogleUtilitiesComponents (1.1.0)
Installing Libuv-gRPC (0.0.10)
Installing MLKitCommon (8.0.0)
Installing MLKitNaturalLanguage (4.2.0)
Installing MLKitTranslate (2.2.0)
Installing PromisesObjC (2.1.1)
Installing Protobuf (3.21.9)
Installing SSZipArchive (2.4.3)
Installing abseil (1.20211102.0)
Installing gRPC-C++ (1.44.0)
Installing gRPC-Core (1.44.0)
Installing leveldb-library (1.22.1)
Installing nanopb (2.30909.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 3 dependencies from the Podfile and 31 total pods installed.

[!] Unable to read the license file `LICENSE` for the spec `GoogleUtilities (7.10.0)`

[!] Unable to read the license file `LICENSE` for the spec `GoogleUtilities (7.10.0)`

[!] [Xcodeproj] Generated duplicate UUIDs:

PBXFileReference -- Pods.xcodeproj/mainGroup/children/children:children:|,|,|,displayName:BoringSSL-GRPC,isa:PBXGroup,name:BoringSSL-GRPC,path:BoringSSL-GRPC,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,displayName:FirebaseAnalytics,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseAnalytics,path:FirebaseAnalytics,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:FirebaseCore,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseCore,path:FirebaseCore,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:FirebaseCoreExtension,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseCoreExtension,path:FirebaseCoreExtension,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:FirebaseCoreInternal,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseCoreInternal,path:FirebaseCoreInternal,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:FirebaseFirestore,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseFirestore,path:FirebaseFirestore,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:FirebaseFirestoreSwift,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseFirestoreSwift,path:FirebaseFirestoreSwift,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,displayName:FirebaseInstanceID,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseInstanceID,path:FirebaseInstanceID,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,displayName:FirebaseSharedSwift,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseSharedSwift,path:FirebaseSharedSwift,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,displayName:FirebaseStorage,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseStorage,path:FirebaseStorage,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,displayName:GTMSessionFetcher,isa:PBXGroup,name:GTMSessionFetcher,path:GTMSessionFetcher,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:GoogleDataTransport,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleDataTransport,path:GoogleDataTransport,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,displayName:GoogleInterchangeUtilities,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleInterchangeUtilities,path:GoogleInterchangeUtilities,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,displayName:GoogleMLKit,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleMLKit,path:GoogleMLKit,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,displayName:GoogleSymbolUtilities,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleSymbolUtilities,path:GoogleSymbolUtilities,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:GoogleToolboxForMac,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleToolboxForMac,path:GoogleToolboxForMac,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,displayName:GoogleUtilities,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleUtilities,path:GoogleUtilities,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:GoogleUtilitiesComponents,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleUtilitiesComponents,path:GoogleUtilitiesComponents,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,displayName:Libuv-gRPC,isa:PBXGroup,name:Libuv-gRPC,path:Libuv-gRPC,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,displayName:MLKitCommon,isa:PBXGroup,name:MLKitCommon,path:MLKitCommon,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,displayName:MLKitNaturalLanguage,isa:PBXGroup,name:MLKitNaturalLanguage,path:MLKitNaturalLanguage,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,displayName:MLKitTranslate,isa:PBXGroup,name:MLKitTranslate,path:MLKitTranslate,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:PromisesObjC,isa:PBXGroup,name:PromisesObjC,path:PromisesObjC,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:Protobuf,isa:PBXGroup,name:Protobuf,path:Protobuf,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:SSZipArchive,isa:PBXGroup,name:SSZipArchive,path:SSZipArchive,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:abseil,isa:PBXGroup,name:abseil,path:abseil,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,displayName:gRPC-C++,isa:PBXGroup,name:gRPC-C++,path:gRPC-C++,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,displayName:gRPC-Core,isa:PBXGroup,name:gRPC-Core,path:gRPC-Core,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:leveldb-library,isa:PBXGroup,name:leveldb-library,path:leveldb-library,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:nanopb,isa:PBXGroup,name:nanopb,path:nanopb,sourceTree:<group>,,displayName:Pods,isa:PBXGroup,name:Pods,sourceTree:<group>,/Pods/children/children:children:|,displayName:Frameworks,isa:PBXGroup,name:Frameworks,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,displayName:Support Files,isa:PBXGroup,name:Support Files,path:../Target Support Files/GoogleUtilities,sourceTree:<group>,,displayName:GoogleUtilities,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleUtilities,path:GoogleUtilities,sourceTree:<group>,/Pods/GoogleUtilities/children/children:displayName:GoogleUtilities.debug.xcconfig,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:text.xcconfig,path:GoogleUtilities.debug.xcconfig,sourceTree:<group>,,displayName:GoogleUtilities.release.xcconfig,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:text.xcconfig,path:GoogleUtilities.release.xcconfig,sourceTree:<group>,,displayName:GoogleUtilities.debug.xcconfig,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:text.xcconfig,path:GoogleUtilities.debug.xcconfig,sourceTree:<group>,,displayName:GoogleUtilities.release.xcconfig,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:text.xcconfig,path:GoogleUtilities.release.xcconfig,sourceTree:<group>,,displayName:Support Files,isa:PBXGroup,name:Support Files,path:../Target Support Files/GoogleUtilities,sourceTree:<group>,/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Support Files/children/displayName:GoogleUtilities.debug.xcconfig,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:text.xcconfig,path:GoogleUtilities.debug.xcconfig,sourceTree:<group>,/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Support Files/GoogleUtilities.debug.xcconfig
PBXFileReference -- Pods.xcodeproj/mainGroup/children/children:children:|,|,|,displayName:BoringSSL-GRPC,isa:PBXGroup,name:BoringSSL-GRPC,path:BoringSSL-GRPC,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,displayName:FirebaseAnalytics,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseAnalytics,path:FirebaseAnalytics,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:FirebaseCore,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseCore,path:FirebaseCore,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:FirebaseCoreExtension,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseCoreExtension,path:FirebaseCoreExtension,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:FirebaseCoreInternal,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseCoreInternal,path:FirebaseCoreInternal,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:FirebaseFirestore,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseFirestore,path:FirebaseFirestore,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:FirebaseFirestoreSwift,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseFirestoreSwift,path:FirebaseFirestoreSwift,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,displayName:FirebaseInstanceID,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseInstanceID,path:FirebaseInstanceID,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,displayName:FirebaseSharedSwift,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseSharedSwift,path:FirebaseSharedSwift,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,displayName:FirebaseStorage,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseStorage,path:FirebaseStorage,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,displayName:GTMSessionFetcher,isa:PBXGroup,name:GTMSessionFetcher,path:GTMSessionFetcher,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:GoogleDataTransport,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleDataTransport,path:GoogleDataTransport,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,displayName:GoogleInterchangeUtilities,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleInterchangeUtilities,path:GoogleInterchangeUtilities,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,displayName:GoogleMLKit,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleMLKit,path:GoogleMLKit,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,displayName:GoogleSymbolUtilities,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleSymbolUtilities,path:GoogleSymbolUtilities,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:GoogleToolboxForMac,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleToolboxForMac,path:GoogleToolboxForMac,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,displayName:GoogleUtilities,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleUtilities,path:GoogleUtilities,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:GoogleUtilitiesComponents,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleUtilitiesComponents,path:GoogleUtilitiesComponents,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,displayName:Libuv-gRPC,isa:PBXGroup,name:Libuv-gRPC,path:Libuv-gRPC,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,displayName:MLKitCommon,isa:PBXGroup,name:MLKitCommon,path:MLKitCommon,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,displayName:MLKitNaturalLanguage,isa:PBXGroup,name:MLKitNaturalLanguage,path:MLKitNaturalLanguage,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,displayName:MLKitTranslate,isa:PBXGroup,name:MLKitTranslate,path:MLKitTranslate,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:PromisesObjC,isa:PBXGroup,name:PromisesObjC,path:PromisesObjC,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:Protobuf,isa:PBXGroup,name:Protobuf,path:Protobuf,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:SSZipArchive,isa:PBXGroup,name:SSZipArchive,path:SSZipArchive,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:abseil,isa:PBXGroup,name:abseil,path:abseil,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,displayName:gRPC-C++,isa:PBXGroup,name:gRPC-C++,path:gRPC-C++,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,displayName:gRPC-Core,isa:PBXGroup,name:gRPC-Core,path:gRPC-Core,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:leveldb-library,isa:PBXGroup,name:leveldb-library,path:leveldb-library,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:nanopb,isa:PBXGroup,name:nanopb,path:nanopb,sourceTree:<group>,,displayName:Pods,isa:PBXGroup,name:Pods,sourceTree:<group>,/Pods/children/children:children:|,displayName:Frameworks,isa:PBXGroup,name:Frameworks,sourceTree:<group>,,children:|,|,|,|,displayName:Support Files,isa:PBXGroup,name:Support Files,path:../Target Support Files/GoogleUtilities,sourceTree:<group>,,displayName:GoogleUtilities,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleUtilities,path:GoogleUtilities,sourceTree:<group>,/Pods/GoogleUtilities/children/children:displayName:GoogleUtilities.debug.xcconfig,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:text.xcconfig,path:GoogleUtilities.debug.xcconfig,sourceTree:<group>,,displayName:GoogleUtilities.release.xcconfig,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:text.xcconfig,path:GoogleUtilities.release.xcconfig,sourceTree:<group>,,displayName:GoogleUtilities.debug.xcconfig,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:text.xcconfig,path:GoogleUtilities.debug.xcconfig,sourceTree:<group>,,displayName:GoogleUtilities.release.xcconfig,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:text.xcconfig,path:GoogleUtilities.release.xcconfig,sourceTree:<group>,,displayName:Support Files,isa:PBXGroup,name:Support Files,path:../Target Support Files/GoogleUtilities,sourceTree:<group>,/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Support Files/children/displayName:GoogleUtilities.release.xcconfig,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:text.xcconfig,path:GoogleUtilities.release.xcconfig,sourceTree:<group>,/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Support Files/GoogleUtilities.release.xcconfig

[!] [Xcodeproj] Generated duplicate UUIDs:

PBXAggregateTarget -- 8D7F5D5DD528D21A72DC87ADA5B12E2D
```

and her is the Podfile:

```
target 'testTranslateAndFirebase' do

 use_frameworks!

 pod 'FirebaseStorage'
 pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
 pod 'GoogleMLKit/Translate', '3.2.0'

end
```

EDIT: - I tried the depreciated 'FirebaseMLNLTranslate' in place of 'GoogleMLKit/Translate' and there is no build error. App builds, runs and translates. How can I get the current GoogleMLKit/Translate working with both firebase pods as it does install and build when in conjunction with a single firebase pod?

Can anyone help or confirm this as a bug?

Comment: TL;DR, add this `platform :ios, '10.0'` to the podfile. See full answer for more info.

Comment: I don't recommend solving this by changing the `platform` since ancient versions of Firebase are installed. I'll write up a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

11/18/22 After this answer was accepted, new data came to light. So I am updating (correcting) with the new info.

The first issue in the question is the platform was not specified like this

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
```

Because it was not, Cocoapods was attempting to install 'ancient' versions of Firebase to keep everything compatible.

The bigger issue is that at this time, Firebase 10 is not compatible with the current MLKit. See this

[Git issue: 10359](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/10359)

The best solution is to force Firebase 9.6 to load by using FirebaseAuth = 9.6.0 - here's an updated and tested podfile

```
project 'Test.xcodeproj'
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'Test' do
 use_frameworks!
 pod 'FirebaseAuth', '= 9.6.0'
 pod 'FirebaseStorage'
 pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
 pod 'GoogleMLKit/Translate'
end
```

which appears to load all of the needed and compatible components

```
Installing BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.24)
Installing FirebaseAppCheckInterop (9.6.0)
Installing FirebaseAuth (9.6.0)
Installing FirebaseAuthInterop (9.6.0)
Installing FirebaseCore (9.6.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (9.6.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreExtension (9.6.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreInternal (9.6.0)
Installing FirebaseFirestore (9.6.0)
Installing FirebaseFirestoreSwift (9.6.0)
Installing FirebaseStorage (9.6.0)
Installing FirebaseStorageInternal (9.6.0)
Installing GTMSessionFetcher (1.7.2)
Installing GoogleDataTransport (9.2.0)
Installing GoogleMLKit (3.2.0)
Installing GoogleToolboxForMac (2.3.2)
Installing GoogleUtilities (7.8.0)
Installing GoogleUtilitiesComponents (1.1.0)
Installing Libuv-gRPC (0.0.10)
Installing MLKitCommon (8.0.0)
Installing MLKitNaturalLanguage (4.2.0)
Installing MLKitTranslate (2.2.0)
Installing PromisesObjC (2.1.1)
Installing Protobuf (3.21.9)
Installing SSZipArchive (2.4.3)
Installing abseil (1.20211102.0)
Installing gRPC-C++ (1.44.0)
Installing gRPC-Core (1.44.0)
Installing leveldb-library (1.22.1)
Installing nanopb (2.30909.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 4 dependencies from the Podfile and 30 total pods installed.
```

I will leave the original answer below because it does successfully install the pods but again, according to Firebase, it's not currently supported and loads older versions of firebase

---

**Important**, ensure your podfile contains (yours is missing this line)

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
```

The 10.0 is important! Setting to 9.0 or even 16 will throw an error.

I built a quick project using that updated podfile and it worked fine - here's my podfile

```
project 'Test.xcodeproj'
platform :ios, '10.0'  

target 'Test' do
 use_frameworks!

 pod 'FirebaseStorage'
 pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
 pod 'GoogleMLKit/Translate'
end
```

and the output

```
Installing BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.7)
Installing FirebaseCore (6.10.4)
Installing FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (1.7.0)
Installing FirebaseFirestore (1.19.0)
Installing FirebaseFirestoreSwift (0.4.0)
Installing FirebaseStorage (3.9.1)
Installing GTMSessionFetcher (1.7.2)
Installing GoogleDataTransport (7.5.1)
Installing GoogleMLKit (0.64.0)
Installing GoogleToolboxForMac (2.3.2)
Installing GoogleUtilities (6.7.2)
Installing GoogleUtilitiesComponents (1.1.0)
Installing MLKitCommon (0.64.0)
Installing MLKitNaturalLanguage (0.64.0)
Installing MLKitTranslate (0.64.0)
Installing PromisesObjC (1.2.12)
Installing Protobuf (3.21.9)
Installing abseil (0.20200225.0)
Installing gRPC-C++ (1.28.2)
Installing gRPC-Core (1.28.2)
Installing leveldb-library (1.22.1)
Installing nanopb (1.30906.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
```

I suggest removing cocoapods from your project first using

```
pod deintegrate
```

Then delete the `podfile.lock` and the `.xcworkspace` file

then update your podfile and then

```
pod setup
pod install
```

Comment: You're right it will build with FirebaseFirestore but I have been using and need FirebaseFirestoreSwift for encoding my firebase models as described here: https://peterfriese.dev/posts/swiftui-firebase-codable/ . + Thanks for saying I can remove the version number from the translate pod. 'GoogleMLKit/Translate', '3.2.0' is what is described in the MLKit guides here: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/language/translation/ios. Removing the version number does not solve the problem though.

Comment: @RossKnipe Gotcha - I see. The issue is in the version of the supported platform in your podfile. I update the top of the question, built it using FirebaseFirestoreSwift and added more info at the bottom. Please look over the updated answer now.

Comment: thanks, that has solved the pod install which now builds. It has introduced quite a few firebasey warnings like  - FirebaseCore/FIRLogger  This old-style function definition is not preceded by a prototype - but I imagine that's for another question if I can't work it out, so I'm marking your answer as the solution.

Comment: I don't recommend this answer since ancient versions of Firebase are installed. I'll write up a better answer.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Can you be more specific? I am happy to update the answer if we can clarify the cause. This was from a fresh install of everything on a brand new iMac (like right out of the box). How could 'ancient' versions of Firebase be installed? All of that was totally fresh.

Comment: When the latest CocoaPods versions are incompatible, CocoaPods can install any set of pods that are compatible. GoogleMLKit doesn't work with Firebase 10.x and CocoaPods chose to install very old versions instead of Firebase 9.x.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Thank you. I thought I had read something about the minimum being 10.x - thanks for that correction. Based on the podfile presented in my answer, which 'Firebase reference' should contain `, '> 9.6'` so I can correct the answer? There's only two 'FirebaseStorage' and 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'?

Comment: Yes. you can correct and I can delete mine.  The minimum supported iOS version in Firebase 10.x changed to iOS 11 and that is why your answer installs a different set of pods.

Answer (score 1):

MLKit is not yet compatible with the latest major version of Firebase 10.x

Details at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/10359

Until MLKit releases, I recommend working around by staying with Firebase 9.x.

Update Podfile references to Firebase with `, '> 9.6'`